# I want to convert an Object to a byte[] using serialization in Java

Tags: java, serialization, byte

Hello I have a class called table. table keeps track of remoteIP, remotePort, macAdd and avgRtt
this is the general structure of it.

```
public class table implements java.io.Serializable{


 String remoteIP;
 int remotePort;
 String macAdd;
 int avgRtt;


public table(String rIP,int rP,String mac,int avRTT){

                remoteIP=rIP;
  remotePort=rP;
  macAdd=mac;
         avgRtt=avRTT;

 }
}
```

I'm new to using serialization, I want to be able to convert this into a byte[] and vice-versa.Does anyone know how I would be able to do that?

Comment: 4 spaces at the beginning of a line denote code, btw - your formatting is a little off.

Comment: Also, I never asked *why* you're doing this - it's a slightly unusual requirement. What's the actual problem you're solving?

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines:

```
table t;
ByteArrayOutputStream aOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oOS = new ObjectOutputStream(aOS);
oOS.writeObject(t);
oOS.close();
byte[] byteArray = aOS.toByteArray();
```

The [Java docs on serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) are really good, and with the above code and them you should be able to write the code to unserialize it, too! You might also find the JavaDoc for [ObjectOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with apache commons quite easily. See [here](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html).